# NSManagedObjects with nullify delete rules on relationships are not being removed manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I was wondering about this problem lately. I am concerned about long-term problems with the given implementation of Core Data below.

Lets say we have a **Task** `NSManagedObject` that has one-to-one relationship to **Album** object with **Nullify** delete rule both ways. Then **Album** has one-to-many relationship to **Photo** object with same delete rule.

The question is theoretical. What happens if **Task** object gets deleted, but developer doesn't delete **Album** and **Photo** objects related to **Task** manually? Is there a possibility of the data corruption this way? Or will Core Data will just grow in size and not complain?

Thank you for your help beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens if **Task** object gets deleted, but developer doesn't delete **Album** and **Photo** objects related to **Task** manually?

Then normal "nullify" behavior applies. The inverse relationship from `Album` to `Task` is set to nil, but nothing else changes. With "nullify" that's all that ever happens, relationships are set to nil when the related object is removed.

> Is there a possibility of the data corruption this way?

Well, you get an `Album` with no associated `Task`. Whether that would be considered corrupt depends on your specific requirements. If every `Album` *must* have a `Task` then you'd probably consider it corrupt. On the other hand if this relationship is optional, then having it be nil is fine. The underlying persistent store file (probably SQLite) is no more likely to be corrupted in this case than in any other case.

> Or will Core Data will just grow in size and not complain?

Deleting managed objects won't make the persistent store file grow. If what you mean is, will the related `Album` and `Photo` objects still exist, then yes, because that's how the design you've described works. Whether that's a problem or not depends again on your specific requirements.

Comment: right the core data models don't really know if an object can live in an unconnected way... it is up to the developer...

Comment: I also agree that it depends on whether this is accepted behaviour or not. Thank you for your answer.